# How to make a longer if rather than a for loop

Tags: python

I have a textfile `names.txt` with names (each line has one name). I want to use all names AT THE SAME TIME in a if clause. Here is what I did:

```
with open("names.txt") as f:   # reading to list
  names = f.read().splitlines() #names contains all names in a list

for name in names:
  if "name" == "John":
    do something...
```

The problem with this code is, that for every name in names.txt the for loop is triggered. But what I actually want to do is to substituate the for loop with a longer if clause:

```
  if (name == "John") or (name2 == "John") or (name3 == "John"): # ...
    do something...
```

The problem is now that I dont know how to make the if clause because the amount of the items (names) in names.txt vary. With `len()` I could get the length but how can I do such a if clause? If a particular `name` matches `John` I need this `name` in a variable for further stuff. I hope you understand what I mean. I dont want to go through a for loop for every name. I want to make one single if clause with all names. Once a name matches I need the name stored in a variable to work with it.

Comment: "If a particular `name` matches `John` I need this `name` in a variable for further stuff [...]" really makes no sense at all, unless you're telling just half the story. If you want to look for names that **contain** `John` on them, then that's something else altogether...

Comment: Why do you want a single conditional instead of a loop?

Comment: If the list of names may be long then you may wish to consider storing the names in a sorted data structure (such as a dictionary) for fast lookup access. Otherwise the answers below should do the job nicely.

Comment: I am cwd'ing on a ftp server and need to check if that name is in another file. If I do that in a foor loop I would make a lot of cwd's. If I would be able to do that in a single if loop this would cost less time. So I need to check lets say 20 names in some directories fast, rather than checking one name in all directories, than the next name in all directories, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this, for example:

```
if any(name == "John" for name in names):
    do something...
```

Edit: Just one thing: this `if` (or the one Sebastian proposes) does what you say first "[...] The problem is now that I dont know how to make the if clause because the amount of the items [...]".

Anyway, I'm going to assume that you are not matching for exact names, because it doesn't make sense, unless you want to count them, which you could do as easily as:

```
johns = names.count("John")
```

Now, if you want the names that *contain* `John`, then you can do:

```
with open("names.txt") as f:
    for name in (n for n in f if "John" in n):
        do some stuff...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perfect for python. Just do this:

```
if "John" in names:
    do something...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop when you find the first `"John"`, you can `break` the loop:

```
for name in names:
    if name == "John": # note no quotes around name
        # do something...
        break
```

This will mean the content of the `if` block runs only once.

Although you can test up-front if if will ever evaluate `True` (i.e. `if "John" in` or `if any(...)`), this *will* mean a loop over enough of the names to find a `"John"` or reach the end of the list.

If you want to know *which `"John"` you're using*, you can use the index too:

```
for index, name in enumerate(names):
    if name == "John":
        print("Found '{0}' at index {1}.".format(name, index))
```

Comment: `"name" == "John"` will always be `False` (yeah, I know that's straight out from OP's post)